# Wireguard only works if I use `wg-quick`

Tags: network-manager, vpn, wireguard

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to use wireguard with the NetworkManager, but does not recognize wireguard

I have tried the following command

```
nmcli connection import type wireguard file "$CONF_FILE"
```

but it throws an error that a VPN plugin for wireguard could not be found.

Instead, with the wg-quick command it works correctly

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 18.04 ships NetworkManager version 1.10.6, which is three years old.

That version of NetworkManager does not support WireGuard. The first NetworkManager version that added support for WireGuard is 1.16.0.